# How to detect if user cancel auto-renewable subscriptions during the free trial period?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Apple's document does not seem to mention this.  So if user cancels an auto-renewable subscription purchased during the free trial period, how do we detect?

In appstore receipt JSON there is this field: `is_trial_period`.  But I think this is for indication of whether the free trial period is over.

The only thing I can think of is this `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL?.path`  and if this is nil than that will indicate the user has not subscribed or cancel within the free trial period.  But for sandbox testing, there is no way to do a cancel during free trial period to test this scenario.

Does anyone have a solid knowledge of this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to support auto-renewing subscriptions, your app needs to periodically submit the app receipt obtained from `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL?.path` to [Apple's receipt validation service](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573).

Contained in the JSON response from this service is the `latest_receipt_info` array.

By examining this array you will be able to determine the currently active subscription(s).

If a user turns off auto-renewal before the expiration of the free trial then `latest_receipt_info` won't contain a purchase with an `expires_date` after the free trial end date

This means, that strictly speaking, you can't "detect a cancellation" as there is no "cancellation"; there just isn't a renewal at the end of the free trial period.

Comment: In sandbox environment, immediately after purchased, the JSON contains only one dictionary object in latest_receipt_info array.  This dictionary has is_trial_period sets to true and expires_date.  If I understand you correctly, if user cancels before the expiration of the free trial and I re-request the app receipt, there should only one dictionary object in latest_receipt_info array and the expires_date field will not be there?

Comment: No, that item will still be there. A user cannot cancel a subscription. They can only turn off auto renewal. Any subscription period that starts, whether trial or paid, continues until the its `expires_date`  It is your apps responsibility to determine what subscriptions are/were active and act accordingly. For example if a user was subscribed last month and isn't now, then they should still have access to last month's content (if your subscription is content related). You may choose not to provide this historical access for content that was a free trial if there isn't an active paid sub

Comment: This does not answer the question. If the user cancels the free trial subscription you can't detect this event until the trial ends, because there won't be a new subscription object in the array.

Comment: That is what I said. A user can't actually cancel a subscription (free or otherwise). They can only turn off the renewal. If they do so during the free trial period then they will simply not enter a paid period at the end of the free period. They will have access for the entirety of the free period.

Comment: In addition, if Apple issues a refund, the receipt will contain a field "cancellation_date". You should check for this field and if you find it, "treat it as if the purchase had never been made."

Comment: If you want to know whether user has cancelled. you can know it before expiry date also. 
you just have to hit apple server with the receipt, it will give you decoded response, in which you just check 'auto_renew_status' inside 'pending_renewal_info' JSON. If it is "0", then auto renew wont happen. if it is "1", then auto renew will happen. I verified it myself. Even documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1 states the same

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry I am a bit confused, what if I want to detect if the user cancelled the auto renewable subscription? i.e. a user subscribed for 1 year then after 1 month he cancelled the renew, how can I know at this moment that the user will be premium user only for extra 11 months?

Comment: If they subscribed for a year, then they have a subscription for a year.If the cancel the auto renewal after a month then they still have a subscription for a year, they just won't renew next year. You don't know that they have turned off the renewal.

Comment: @Paulw11 did you try what user3247895 said in the previous comment? According to Apple documentation, it should be possible to detect auto-renewable state with the `pending_renewal_info` property of `verifyReceipt` response. Does it work?

Answer (score 7):

This is possible with the web hook feature in iTunes Connect.

When you set a path for the `Subscription Status URL` of your app the App Store server will call that URL when the subscription status changes.

Currently the following key events will trigger the call:

- **INITIAL_BUY** Initial purchase of the subscription.
- **CANCEL** Subscription was canceled by Apple customer support.
- **RENEWAL** Automatic renewal was successful for an expired subscription.
- **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL** Customer renewed a subscription interactively after it lapsed, either by using your app’s interface or on the App
  Store in account settings.
- **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREFERENCE** Customer changed the plan that takes affect at the next subscription renewal.
- **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS** Subscription has expired and customer resubscribed to the same or another plan.

More can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6).

Comment: But do we get notified right at the moment when the user set their subscription to Not Renew? It looks like CANCEL is only when Apple Support is involved.

Comment: @Say.My.Name. That is now available with DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS

Comment: what is meaning if there is a INITIAL_BUY and auto_renew_status: false.
does it make sense?

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to do this is to check the auto-renew preference on the receipt. If you want to get notified of this even if the user doesn't open your app (or deletes it) you'll need to store and refresh the receipt on your server. There are 3 fields that you should be concerned with to detect a cancellation.

1. Expiration Date (lets you know if subscription is still active)
2. Auto-renew status (lets you know if the user "cancelled")
3. Cancellation Date (tells you why subscription cancelled by support)

You should check for receipts that are not expired, not cancelled and have an auto-renew status of "0". These will be users that are in a free trial, but have auto-renew turned off. Unfortunately, the App Store Connect Subscription Status Notifications don't report this to you.

Here's a good blog post that goes over a little more of the the details: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Comment: I have both: Active users with auto_status_reniew: false AND DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS of trial users. When is what sent? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got the json data about receipt:

```
let sharedSecret = "..."   //you can find this string on AppStoreConnect-IAP

if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

do {
   let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)

   let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
   AF.request("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", method: .post, parameters: ["receipt-data":receiptString, "password": sharedSecret], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
   .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
         print(response)
    })
 }
catch { 
print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

If you want a production URL, not the Sandbox, change the url to `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`
In the `response` you will find all data you need.
Note that you need to include this in the `Podfile` : `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'`

Comment: I got an error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException