# How to detect subscription cancellation in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have implemented subscription to my mobile application that was developed using Xamarin.iOS.
But if the user cancels their subscription, how can I get that event?

```cs
internal class BillingService : SKProductsRequestDelegate
{
    private BillingService() {...}

    public void CompleteTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction t) {...}
    public void FailedTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction t) {...}
    public void RestoreTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction t) {...}

    internal class CustomPaymentObserver : SKPaymentTransactionObserver
    {
        public override voide RestoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError(...) {}
        public override voide RestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(...){}
        public override void UpdatedTransactions(...){}
    }
}
```

This is simple work flow of BillingService code.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271402/how-to-detect-if-user-cancel-auto-renewable-subscriptions-during-the-free-trial may help.

Comment: did you have any solutions? I'm having the same question as yours