# Need to know when someone cancels a renewable subscription

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, webhooks, storekit

Good day, 
Can someone please tell me how can I know track an event in my code/server when someone cancels a auto-renewable subscription from itunes/appleid
Thankyou

Comment: Did you see this thread ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271402/how-to-detect-if-user-cancel-auto-renewable-subscriptions-during-the-free-trial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if user cancel auto-renewable subscriptions during the free trial period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271402/how-to-detect-if-user-cancel-auto-renewable-subscriptions-during-the-free-trial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check when someone cancels a renewable subscription, you need to periodically refresh the receipt on your server and check the:

1. Expiration Date (lets you know if subscription is still active)
2. Auto-renew status (lets you know if the user "cancelled")
3. Cancellation Date (tells you why subscription cancelled by support)

Usually developers get 2 and 3 confused. Apple doesn't consider a user opting out of auto-renew a "cancellation" - when in fact that's what most developers would consider a cancellation. For this reason, it's NOT sufficient to listen for `CANCEL` events with the [subscription status notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW13).

Here's a good blog post that goes over the details: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)